# Reliable PostgreSQL IDE/Database Developer Tool

Tags: sql, postgresql, ide

Can someone recommend a great IDE/Database Developer Tool for Postgres 8.4. We are currently using EMS SQL Manager but it has so many bugs and shortcomings that its getting on my nerves. I reported the bugs to EMS but they have not been fixed yet.

I wonder what do people use for PostgresSQL development? Windows/Linux, commercial/free, standalone/eclipse plug-in, it does not matter as much. I just want a reliable tool that works and does not blow up in my face.

On PostgreSQL DB we do and would like to have IDE support for.

1. Tables, views, indexes, triggers
2. SQL, plpgsql, and python procedures that return single values, set of values or tables
3. SQL query and performance monitoring
4. DB role management
5. Good transaction support straight from GUI as well as support for BEGIN, COMMIT, etc

Any recommendations are welcome.

Edit: After many months we are still using EMS SQL Manager. I got used to certain shortcomings, some bug were fixed. I tried every possible PostgreSQL management program I could get my hands on and still in my opinion EMS SQL Manager is still the best.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7654987/939860

Comment: @Erwin link is broken?

Comment: @sMaN: The link is good, but some overzealous users deleted the question. I disagree and voted to undelete. We'll see if it goes through.

Answer (score 6):

[pgAdmin](http://www.pgadmin.org/) is a popular one. It's free, and it runs on Windows and Linux. It's been a while since I have used it but I found it to be quite stable. Wasn't fond of the procedure code editor - it worked, I just didn't like it (but now I can't remember why, it was probably a minor thing).

Comment: pgAdmin is a great tool for whats its worth (free, that it), but it is far from full IDE. Its object editor is just a dialog. How do you supposed to develop in a dialog? Code completion is absent. 

Its better that text editor + psql shell but far from full development environment.

Comment: Actually, code completion sort of exists, but you have to turn it on in the options menu. In latest version you also have the graphical interfce to quickly whip up some code that you can elaborate on afterwards using the editor. Update: autocompletions using TAB: http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/1.10/options-tab3.html

Comment: @Mike Starov: what do you recommend then?

Answer (score 2):

Lightning Admin, commercial, postgreSQL and mysql, $50. The developer is very pro postgreSQL.

http://lightningadmin.com/

Comment: The link is bad and the site seems to be offline.

Comment: Tried it. Seems nice but underdeveloped. Crashed few time time before I was able to open it. It lacks many features included in EMS SQL Manager.